# Escaping User Inputted URLs

Tags: php

I have a website that allows users to input URLs to websites to share with other users.

We currently htmlentities() the URLs when showing them to other users but this will occasionally cause a broken URL due to a valid character being converted.

What's the best way to remove potentially malicious characters from the URLs while breaking as few URLs as possible?

```
Example
Original URL: website.com?foo=1&bar=2
Escaped/Broken URL: website.com?foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

Comment: Be more precise, give an example. "Breaks" how? Output to where?

Comment: Can you show an example of a URL that breaks?

Comment: Example added above. Output to HTML

Comment: That's not a broken url, that's perfectly correct in html.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I was attempting to input the URLs directly into my browser which caused for the broken links. I did not realize when in an anchor tag and clicked the browser will automatically convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you are outputting to, but if it is html, you can use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) instead. That will only escape the characters that have special meaning in html.

Comment: Unfortunately this will potentially break any URL with an ampersand (&).

Comment: @Chip It does not break it, put it in a `href` or as text and it will display and work correctly.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I was attempting to input the URLs directly into my browser which caused for the broken links. I did not realize when in an anchor tag and clicked the browser will automatically convert it.

Answer (score -1):

You should use REGEX to meet you custom rules.